# Laravel bulk insert with one-to-one relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, orm, bulkinsert

I know that I can insert multiple records in laravel with:

```
$data = [
    ['name' => '...', 'age' => ...],
    ['name' => '...', 'age' => ...],
    ['name' => '...', 'age' => ...],
];
Model::insert($data);
```

But is is possible to do a bulk insert that also has a one-to-one relation? So that I insert data into two databases at the same time?

Something like:

$data = [
    ['name' => '...', 'age' => ...],
    ['name' => '...', 'age' => ...],
    ['name' => '...', 'age' => ...],
];

```
Model::withSecondTable()->insert($data);
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Because you need some ids from a parent table for data insertion to be added for a related table.

Comment: I don't see any relation in your example.

Comment: @RazaMehdi yea thats the problem. But not I was thinking of only doing a bulk insert of all users then save the ids inserted and do another insert with the user details table, that way I would still only create 2 insert queries instead of doing a loop and making 20+ insert queries

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. For example:

###User Model:

```
public function item()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Item');
}
```

###Item Model:

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->hasMany('User');
}
```

To save a User from the Item perspective, you do this:

```
$item->users()->save($user);
```

To associate an item with a user, you do this:

```
$user->item()->associate($item);
$user->save();
```

Comment: But can I do a bulk insert using this? Or must I loop through my array of users and insert each one by one? That would create a lot of inserts instead of just doing one insert sql once

Comment: This does not explain how to do bulk insertions with the relationship, thus not providing an answer to the questions asked by OP.